# navigating an array of objects in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

Need help forming **javascript** objects from **MySQL** rows of data. I'm using **IE9** and **Chrome** on **Windows-7**.

I've managed to get what I believe to be an array (of objects) in Javascript from mySQL data. I can use alerts to see the whole array, as well as one individual object, as in my code.

What I cannot do yet is navigate a particular object's properties (the column values of a particular row in the database).

What I need to do is iterate through `myObjects`, and use the property values in each to create some graphics. I also need to be able to retrieve each object's properties at any time going forward as well.

UPDATE: including my php located in head html object:

```
    <?php
    //------------------- constants --------------------
    $objects = array();
    $jsonData = "";
    //------------------- database connection ----------
    $data_source = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDB';
    $db_user = 'root';
    $db_password = 'password';
    $conn = new PDO($data_source, $db_user, $db_password,
              array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
                    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT));
    //prepare query
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblbranchstatus");
    $stmt->execute();
    //fetch each row of results
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $rows[] = json_encode($row);
    }
?>

var ART = {};
//capture data from database as json string data
ART.strJSON = <? php echo json_encode($rows); ?> ;
//capture json string data as array of javascript objects
//using 'eval' cause I know this data's source and I couldn't get JSON.parse to work
ART.myObjects = eval(ART.strJSON);
ART.branch = ART.myObjects[6];
alert(ART.branch); // this gives me the expected object {"a":"aa", "b":"bb"...}
alert(ART.branch.a); // can't retrieve the property - gives me 'undefined'
```

Comment: Could you post an example output for `json_encode($rows);`?

Comment: You shouldn't need `JSON.parse` *or* `eval`.  Valid JS should be emitted.

Comment: alert( ART.strJSON[6].a ) might surprise you...

Comment: @bfavaretto the output for json_encode($rows); is ["{\"osj\":\"40D\",\"region\":\"FID\",...},{...}, "]  So, it looks like it might actually be one long string, as hinted by others. I'm kind of lost as to how to do this.

Comment: @dandavis alert(ART.strJSON[6].a) gives me undefined, I guess due to this unexpected string wrap around my JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't look like the right thing to do. Here's what you should be doing:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Don't do `json_encode()` on each row.

```
ART.myObjects = <?php echo json_encode($rows); ?>;
```

You can immediately use the output of `json_encode($rows)` in your script.

**Update**

As rightfully [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407771/navigating-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript/16431434?noredirect=1#comment23565151_16431434) by [bfavaretto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/825789/bfavaretto), you can make this even shorter by encoding all rows in one go:

```
ART.myObjects = <?php echo json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)); ?>;
```

Comment: Makes sense, but I just get [object Object],... from `alert(ART.myObjects);`

Comment: @csupak Don't use `alert()` to debug! Use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: @csupak You could also use `json_encode($stmt->fetchAll((PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`, so the while loop is not even needed. The problem is clear now, you were double encoding your array.

Comment: Yes, this works! Thanks so much. Note the comment version here has an extra paren, but Jack's update above is correct. Thanks again to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I would check if ART.branch is actually a string with the JSON notation rather than the actual object.

Comment: Yes, this might be the issue. When I echo from php, I'm getting the whole shebang wrapped with ["..."]. I've updated my post with my php code as well. Can you help me get my head around this?